# Can not attach multiple files in the attachment of email in C#

Tags: c#, email

In my project i need to attach multiple files to send mail and i am doing it as

```
        if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox6.Text += fDialog.FileName.ToString() + ";";
        }
```

Here i am attaching the file in textbox6

I am separating the paths of the different attachment file using ";" and then i separate those paths of the attachment as follows and then send it.

```
         System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        foreach (string m in textBox6.Text.Split(';'))
        {
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(m);
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }
```

This method don't work for me. But when i send mail with single attachment with the following code it just work fine

```
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(textBox6.Text.ToString());
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Someone please help. I have been working this whole day and could not figure it out.

Comment: have you debugged it?  actually stepped through in a debugger?  i'd bet that your paths aren't what you think they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will solve your problem completely http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/CSharpGmail

Comment: Thanks buddy, you saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be :

```
foreach (string m in textBox6.Text.Split(';'))
{
   System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(m);
   message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: @user1478137, did you debugged the code and is the debugger is entering in the loop? also share the string that you have in your text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use file stream instead of link on file:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentFileStream, fileNameOnly));
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a Attachmentlistbox then-

```
                if (Attachmentlistbox.Items.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Attachmentlistbox.Items.Count; i++)
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Attachmentlistbox.Items[i].ToString()));
                }
```

Comment: Create a listbox & add your file path in listbox by  OpenFileDialog Method.. Then this code must work.... If not working, let me know whats error showing....