# Cannot reuse email attachment in multiple emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently providing a form in MVC3 for a user to fill in some fields and attach a file. On submission, I send the information posted (with the attachment) twice... one to the poster as a receipt, and the second to another target email.

The issue that I am having is the first email gets sent successfully with the right attachemnt. The second email gets sent out with an attached file that is 0 in size. It seems that after I make an attachment object from a file upload, I cannot reuse it again. Using the debugger I can see that the file upload object is still in memory, buts its ContentLength becomes 0.

So in the following example, if I simplify my code as follows:

```
public static void SendDummyEmail1()
{
    using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com"))
    {
        mailMessage.Subject = "Email Subject"
        mailMessage.Body = Razor.Parse(template, (dynamic)dynamicTokens);
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        if (_fileUpload != null && _fileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var attachment = new Attachment(_fileUpload.InputStream, _fileUpload.FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(_fileUpload.FileName);
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }

        SendMail(mailMessage);
    }
}

public static void SendMail(MailMessage message)
{
    var client = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SmtpHostname],
        Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SmtpPortNumber]),
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        EnableSsl = true,  
    };

    // Work around remote certificate validation
    // Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    client.Send(message);
}
```

If I was to call the above method twice in a row, the first email will go through successfully. The second email will go through but with no attachment because the ContentLength goes to 0.

```
SendDummyEmail1();
SendDummyEmail1();
```

Comment: you already posted the file to the server for first time. so next time there is no files in request.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356817/can-not-attach-multiple-files-in-the-attachment-of-email-in-c-sharp/27705328#27705328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose `_fileUpload.InputStream.CanSeek` in your case equals to `false`, which means you cannot wind it up again (`Position = 0`) and read from it. Try to copy uploaded file stream into memory stream first and then use it instead of initial stream, like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
_fileUpload.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
SendDummyEmail1(data);
SendDummyEmail1(data);

public static void SendDummyEmail1(byte[] fileContent)
{
 ...
 var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(fileContent), ...
}
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly Dima, but it didn't work. Both emails got sent out with an empty attachment file.

Comment: I have update code in answer, does your solution looks similar?

Answer (score 3):

Use a memory stream as your instance variable rather than _fileUpload.
Then clone that to a new steam for each email (so don't have multiple consumers). Remember to reset the streams after writing to them so that the attachment read starts from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Store uploaded file on server and use file path in Attachment.

```
var attachment = new Attachment(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Delete uploaded file if require after sending email.

Comment: That doesn't explain the above behaviour. It is also too much of a hassle saving the file on the server with a unique name, and cleaning up after sending.